# cakephp email component phpmailer

Tags: email, cakephp, components, php

I am using CakePHP 1.2 version and trying to send an email with PHPMailer library for my email function however while trying to send an email, it gets below mention error:

Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /var/www/xyz/app/controllers/components/email.php on line 80

Tried different ways to include vendor library into controller/app controller files, but it doesn't help much to resolve an error.

Any clues/ideas to resolve it ASAP.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use

```
App::import('Vendor', 'PhpMailer', array('file' => 'phpmailer' . DS . 'class.phpmailer.php'));
```

?

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.yflying.com/integrate-cakephp-with-phpmailer/) for phpmailer and Cakephp

Comment: thanks for answer, yes we're using it the same. But now we're using its inbuilt email function with library, which works fine now.